# Node.js scheduling function in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm working on a project on Node.js. I want to execute some conditional code portion after waiting for five minutes since the last code does. I only need it to run once that way (not everyday or ...). The rest of the code will take over but when it ticks five minute, that will execute. Can I accomplish this?

EDIT: The code from [**Abdennour TOUMI**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747579/abdennour-toumi) partially works. But his way of denoting the minute by the variable didn't work for me. So I made the following edit according to the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) from the module's page.

```
            var schedule = require('node-schedule');

            var AFTER_5_MIN=new Date(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5*60000))
            var date = new Date(AFTER_5_MIN);
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function() {
                if(condition1){
                     // Runned once --> Thus, you need to cancel it
                     // code here, than code to run once   
                    j.cancel();
                }else{

                    //it will be repeated
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your mistake is use 5 fields & the right is 6 fields .

- `* 0 * * * *` --> For each hour at the 0 minute of that hour.

To start after 5 minutes , you could calculate the minute of hour after 5 minutes :

```
     var schedule = require('node-schedule');

               
     var AFTER_5_MIN=new Date(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5*60000)).getMinutes();   
                  
     var j = schedule.scheduleJob(`* ${AFTER_5_MIN} * * * *`, function() {
                    if(condition1){
                         // Runned once --> Thus, you need to cancel it
                         // code here, than code to run once   
                        j.cancel();
                    }else{

                        //it will be repeated
                     }
                });
```

Comment: @unkown .. plz, check now .. you miss the last  star in the first argument

Comment: Thanks. I am testing it now again. I thought the first "seconds" field is optional. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: Hi, Abdennour. It would be great if you updated the code to give the whole time parameter as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use `setTimeout()`?

```
const WAIT_TIME = (60 * 5) * 1000; //5 Minutes

var timer = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Cron job works!')
}, WAIT_TIME);

/*
 * If conditions change in this five minutes and you need to cancel executing
 * the callback above, you can clear the timer
 * clearTimeout(timer);
 */
```

Comment: Thanks. Did this suspend all the below functions until the five minutes up? I want the execution to continue whereas it will get back & run the enclosed code after five minutes.